# Why are there open connections on my Heroku app's PostgreSQL database? How do I close them?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

My Heroku app is [www.inflationtrends.com](http://www.inflationtrends.com).

Usually, when I run "pg:info" in Git Bash to see how many connections there are, that number is zero.

Recently, I've seen a spike in traffic -- not much, only a little over 1,000 in the past 48 hours -- and when I ran "pg:info" this morning (around 11 a.m. Eastern time), the result shows that there are 4 or 5 open connections.

My app is run using the Ruby gem Sinatra. In the Sinatra file, I have the following code:

```
after do
    DB.disconnect
end
```

The "after do" loop disconnects from the PostgreSQL database after a page is loaded.

The variable "DB" has the connection info for my PostgreSQL database (username, password, host, port number, SSL mode requirement):

```
DB = Sequel.postgres(
        db_name,
        :user=>user,
        :password=>password,
        :host=>host,
        :port=>port,
        :sslmode=>sslmode
    )
```

Is there some reason that there are open connections? Are there ways to close these connections? Are there more efficient ways to handle this situation?

Comment: Have a look here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way to check the number of open connections on Heroku is to type this into your console/terminal and replace "myapp" with your app's name:

heroku pg:info -a myapp

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that perhaps your site is getting traffic? When people visit your site and use your application connections will be opened.

Try adding some tracking code (such as Google Analytics) to your web pages, then check if the number of recorded visitors matches the number of open connections.

It is also possible that the database has connections opened by various maintenance tasks, such as backing up.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed the following toolbelt add-on which worked perfectly.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras#usage

heroku pg:killall --app xyz